# How do i dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu without having to go through 2 windows when i boot ubuntu?

Tags: boot

So, here's the deal.

I want to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 and i do know how do to that. my problem is,
i don't want to go through 2 screens when i dual boot ubuntu! is that possible?

[here is the second screen i don't want to go through!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZM31.png)

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And change GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY to true(remember to remove # at the beginning).

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see a bootloader to choose which OS to run then perhaps install one in a virtual machine in the other.

Alternatively change the time that the boot menu is there.

I'm not really understanding why you'd not want to see something to enable you to choose between Ubuntu and Windows 7 in a dual boot - could you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly You asking is not getting clear if u want that u not see any booting menu then u should use [**Virtualbox**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation) .

In other case if you want 2 install ubuntu over windows 7 then u must see this [guide to install ubuntu over windows](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html)

See Further help :

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation
- https://www.virtualbox.org/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot